# Arduino how to Use sda and scl pin(20 and 21) as gpio pins

Tags: arduino

I want to use sda and scl pin as GPIO pins.How can I do that?
I have used all the pins including analog pins.Only left pins are SDA , SCL and SS pins.
Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: This is not related to programing, or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which chip your using, but if you're using the popular ATMega328P, the SDA, SCL and SS pins are just dual functions on existing ports.

[image]

You can see in the image above that the pins your looking for can be accessed via:

1. SDA = PC4 (bit 4 of Port C)
2. SCL = PC5 (bit 5 of Port C)
3. SS = PB2 (bit 2 of Port B)

So you can write to SDA normally:

```
PORTC |= (1 << PC4); // Sets "SDA" to high
```

For info on other ATMega chips see the data sheet for the chip you are using.  SCL, SDA and SS are probably mapped to different ports.

Answer (score 1):

@Honney! Dylan is right. You can set 0 or 1 on SDA (bit4 of port C) in this way. In case you did not understand his code, follow the one below.

In order to set 4th bit to **HIGH** (1), we shall **Bitwise OR** the port with itself.

`PORTC = PORTC | 0b00010000`   // 4th bit willl change to HIGH leaving other bits unchanged

Similarly, to set 4th bit to **LOW** (0), we will use the **Bitwise AND**.

`PORTC = PORTC & 0b11101111`  // 4th bit will be set to 0 leaving other bits unchanged

Note that:

- `0b00010000=1<<4`
- `0b11101111=~(0b00010000)`